# Looking for a free quiz plugin which saves the candidates answers for review

Tags: plugins

I am trying to create a nice quiz for my students which is not single or multiple choice. My questions are about historical topics or books so the students might add a couple of sentences as answers.
Therefore I want to save the results and later on check them. Currently I have HD Quiz installed and their additonal plugin to save results, but unfortunatly it just saves how many questions where answered right or wrong.
Is there any plugin available which saves the text as result or some workaround?

Comment: I expect there's a hook or similar you can use to do that yourself with HD Quiz. I'd ask the authors of that if you haven't already.

Comment: It's my fist Wordpress page after ages, i haven't taken any steps besides checking the plugin ootb and asking here. Thanks for the idea, will give it a try !

Comment: @Rup I did find another free plugin which offers all the functionality i need. See my answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The free plugin - QSM Quiz and Survey Master does offer this functionality in the free version.
You can define whether the user has to be logged in or not etc.
As answer to your question you select "short answer" and the answer will be stored for later review.